# iterate through mdiarea subwindows

Tags: qt, qdialog, qmdiarea

I have a mdiArea. I add subwindows to this mdiArea every time an image is opened. The widget I set for each subwindow is imageFileDialog which inherits from the QDialog. Within this dialog I have a spinbox. I want to be able to set the value of this spinbox for every dialog I have in the mdiArea after they have been created. I do not know how to iterate through the dialogs. I tried to think of ways to do this.

```
for (int j=0; j < ui->mdiArea->subWindowList().size(); j++)
{
    imageFileDialog *ifd = ui->mdiArea->subWindowList()[j]->widget();
    ifd->setSpinBox(0);
}
```

but I have an error because I cannot cast the widget as my imageFileDialog class that inherits from QDialog.

I though I might be able to set a connection upon creation of my imageFileDialog:

```
imageFileDialog *ifd = new imageFileDialog();
ifd->connect(this, SIGNAL(emitImageFileValue(double)), SLOT(ifd->setSpinBox(double)));
subWindow1->setWidget(ifd);
```

but this is unlike any connection I've tried to make before. Everything compiles fine, but the signal emitted does not reach my slot. I'm hoping someone has tried this before and has some suggestions! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [qobject_cast](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast) for the first problem and for the second issue you need to pass only the slot name to the *SLOT()* macro (without *ifd->*), or pass the *ifd* pointer as separate parameter to connect, something like:

```
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(emitImageFileValue(double)), idf, SLOT(setSpinBox(double)));
```

Comment: thank you! was an easy change for me to make, and it worked like a charm. I ended up changing the connection, and decided not to iterate through the subwindows.